# django how to create instance of user

Tags: django

I am creating a simple application, successfully created for a single user, but I want to develop for multiple users, but unable to do so...  i.e. user A can create his task and save in the database. similar B user can create tasks and store in the database. and each can see their own tasks I am newbie unable to proceed with the creation of instance can someone please guide me or point me to a blog ( searched online but no help ) I already asked this question however i was not clear ( [django each user needs to create and view data Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64382387/django-each-user-needs-to-create-and-view-data-issue)) hope now I am clear.

My model :

from django.contrib.auth.models import User, AbstractUser
from django.db import models

```
# Create your models here.
from django.db.models import Sum, Avg

class Task(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False,blank=True)
    purchase_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False,auto_now=False,blank=True,null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(max_length=5,default='0.00',editable=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    @classmethod
    def get_price_total(cls):
        total = cls.objects.aggregate(total=Sum("price"))['total']
        print(total)
        return total
```

**Views**

```
def createTask(request):
    form = TaskForm()

    if request.method =='POST':
        form=TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return redirect('query')

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'tasks/create.html',context)

def display(request):
  #  tasks = Task.objects.all()
    tasks = request.user.task_set.all()
    form = TaskForm()
    if request.method =='POST':

        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()

        return redirect('/')
    #    tasks= task.objects.all()
        print("tasks",Task.get_price_total)
        context = {'tasks':tasks,'form':form,'Totalprice':Task.get_price_total}
        return render(request,'tasks/products.html',context)
```

**urls**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    #path('', views.index, name="list"),
    path('', views.query, name="query"),
    path('create/', views.createTask, name="create"),
    path('update_task/<str:pk>/', views.updateTask, name="update_task"),
    path('register/', views.registerPage,name="register"),
    path('login/', views.loginPage,name="login"),
    path('logout/', views.logoutUser,name="logout"),
    path('delete/<str:pk>/', views.deleteTask, name="delete"),
    path('query/', views.query, name="query"),
    path('products/', views.display, name="products"),
    path('search/', views.showresults, name="search"),
    ]
```

**Error (output)**

```
Internal Server Error: /products/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\s5114509\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\s5114509\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The view tasks.views.display didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
[21/Oct/2020 14:35:59] "GET /products/ HTTP/1.1" 500 60680
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I heard it sounds lke you want to save a task when a user creates one. You don't want to include the user field in the form. You have to first get the model instance returned by the `TaskForm.save()` method. Now you have to assign the `user` field to the `request.user` since the user is authenticated.  Here is how you can achieve that.

```
def createTask(request):
    form = TaskForm()
    task = None

    if request.method =='POST':
        form=TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #Just get the Task instance do not make any commitments to database
            task = form.save(commit=False)
            #Now update the user 
            task.user = request.user
            #Finally save to database
            task.save()

            return redirect('query')

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'tasks/create.html',context)
```

On display you are getting an error because you are return a response only when a POST request is made. Check you identation and correct it. Identation mean scope in python. Check I have modified you code

```
def display(request):
    #tasks = Task.objects.all()
    tasks = request.user.task_set.all()
    form = TaskForm()
    if request.method =='POST':

        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()

        return redirect('/')
        #tasks= task.objects.all()
        print("tasks",Task.get_price_total)
        
    context = {'tasks':tasks,'form':form,'Totalprice':Task.get_price_total}
    return render(request,'tasks/products.html',context)
```

Take a look at [python identation](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_indentation.asp#:%7E:text=Indentation%20refers%20to%20the%20spaces,indicate%20a%20block%20of%20code.)

Comment: Thank you very much it worked, and how about listing the Task created by only that user

Comment: ```request.user.task_set.all()``` will return all the tasks created by that user.

Comment: it's because you are only returning a response only when POST request is made. Check the answer I have modified it.

Comment: it's because you are only returning a response only when POST request is made. Check the answer I have modified it.